# Why does script run from bamboo show deleted branches?

Tags: git, powershell, branch, cicd, bamboo

I need to write a script that checks if there are branches in repositories, that have not been active for the past 14 days. It will be run from Bamboo plan.

It will check 4 repositories, that have been added to the plan using Bamboos build in 'Source Code Checkout'. The problem is that while this works on my local machine, when its run from the Bamboo plan, it also shows deleted branches from each repository.

```
# Get all the *Repo folder names
$root = (Get-Location).Path
$directories = (Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter "*Repo")
$repositories = @()

foreach ($directory in $directories) {
    $repositories += $directory.Name
}

$emailBody = "Hi, these are the branches for all the repos that have not been updated for at least $maxInactiveDays days.`n"

foreach ($repo in $repositories) {
    $repoPath = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath $repo
    Write-Output $repoPath
    Set-Location -Path $repoPath
    

    Write-Output "Will do: git fetch --prune "
    git fetch --prune origin

    $branches = git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate' --format='%(refname:short) %(committerdate:iso8601) %(authorname)' refs/remotes/origin/  
    $branchCount = 0
    $inactiveBranches= @()
    foreach ($branch in $branches) {
    
        $branchInfo = $branch -split ' ', 3
        $branchName = $branchInfo[0]
        $dateString = $branchInfo[1]
        $author = $branchInfo[2]
        $date = [datetime]::Parse($dateString)


        $currentDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
        $days = (New-TimeSpan -Start $date -End $currentDate).Days
        if ($days -ge $maxInactiveDays) {
            $branchCount += 1
            $inactiveBranches += "`t Last Update: $date `t By: $author `t Branch Name: $branchName `n"
        }
       
    }
    $emailBody += "In $repo there are $branchCount inactive branches: `n"
    $emailBody += $inactiveBranches
    $branchCount = 0
} 

Write-Output $emailBody
```

I've tried to add the Force Clean Build in bamboo, tried using `git fetch --prune` as well as g`it remote prune origin`, but nothing seems to be fixing it. I've also tried to change the code to use `git branch -r`  but it also shows the deleted branches.

I'm not sure why it runs OK locally, but from the bamboo plan it shows the deleted branches